# If a sequence converges, so does its norm

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{u_k\}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that if $u_k$ converges, then $\{||u_n||\}$ converges.

Comment: Please search first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: What happens if $\|u_k\|$ diverges, but $u_k$ converges?  In that case, $\|u_k-L\|\geq\left|\|u_k\|-\|L\|\right|$ will not be within $\delta$ of $0$ infinitely often.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$|\|{\bf x}\|-\|{\bf y}\|| \leq \|{\bf x}-{\bf y}\|,\quad \forall\,{\bf x},{\bf y}\in \Bbb R^n.$$